# woocommerce ajax in the front-end not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I try to use woocommerce Ajax, I find a lot example online, none of them works.
could someone take a look on my code, where's the problem.

```html
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'mmy_real' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action', 'mmy_real' );



function mmy_real(){

 check_ajax_referer( 'my-special-string', 'security' );
 
 
 $make = $_SESSION['vpf']['search']['make'];
 $model = $_SESSION['vpf']['search']['model'];
 $year = $_SESSION['vpf']['search']['year_id'];
 
 die();
}



function mmy_script(){
 
 wp_register_script( "hover_script", get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/mmy.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true  );
 wp_localize_script( 'hover_script', 'mmy', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),'security' => wp_create_nonce( 'my-special-string' ))); 
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
 wp_enqueue_script( 'hover_script' );
}

add_action('init', 'mmy_script');
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 

   
 
 jQuery.ajax({ 
   
   type: "post",
   url : mmy.ajaxurl,
   data:{
    action:"mmy_real",
    make: "make",
    model: "model",
    year: "year"
    },
   success: function( response ) {
    alert("success");
     }
   });

 
});
```

I test in localhost. It won't alert success messagebox, if I change url to localhost/fhgroupauto/test.php  . it will alert success .

I don't know what do i miss for this .

Thanks

Comment: I try to use it in https://fhallseason.com/  "shop by vehicle", after I activate the wp fastest cache, I have to use ajax to change this .  I want this work when page loaded.

Comment: I guess it's pretty simple. I just want to use woocommerce ajax, but when I use the online code, that don't work.  all the code include above.   from php files to js files.

Answer (score 0):

The value of "action" is wrong.

You add the hook "wp_ajax_my_action" and "wp_ajax_nopriv_my_action", so the string after "wp_ajax_" and "wp_ajax_nopriv_" is the parameter for the "action" key.

Which means your data array for the ajax call should look like this:

```
data:{
   action: "my_action",
   make: "make",
   model: "model",
   year: "year"
},
```

[For more information see the Wordpress documentation - AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side)